# How street name is detected in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, latitude-longitude

i would like to know how street name of every street in world is identified in this google maps. how google maps is able to find the current street in which user is present just with the latitude and longitude information.

Comment: Please check Geocoder http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: actually what i want to know is exact implementation of how this geocoding process works not just the usage. for my project i need to detect the location say from 10m in a particular road and display a particular message which could change in the same road itself

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting your requirement, I believe there is not one method to do this. If you have database which can give you address using lat and long then you can query that db using that or by using zip code. Else I will highly recommend you first read how lat and long are associated with any location on earth and then develope everything on your own which will be redundant task. Long ago I used this kind of query for location details in Postgres https://www.thutat.com/web/en/programming-and-tech-stuff/web-programming/postgres-query-with-gps-distance-calculations-without-postgis/

Comment: @RamIndani The database will not get the hosuenumber. This is a complex task, which cannot be calculated by the data base (except whren having a special Adress Match plugin). And it is specific for each digital road map provider.

Answer (score 0):

Google uses data from TomTom and other data providers.
The TomTom product containing the digital road map is called MultiNet.
In that specification you can read how house numbers and road names are exactly organized.

The adress is found out by first mathcing the point to a road link.
A road link is a line between one street crossing to the next.
Then the relative position within that (poly-) line is determined.
for example the coordinate is related to road link x at position 30% from start of road link.

This gives the street name, since each link have a street name assigned.
To get the street number one looks up the start house number and the end of link house number and interpolates in between (using for example the value of 30% from above).

When knowning the direction of movement addioanlly to the lat, lon, the it is clear whether the left or right house  lanes are meant. This, too is considred when lookuing up the start and end house number.

In praxis the hosue number matching is more complex, since different numbering schemes for different roads exist.